# OnItemSelected method not invoking when selecting any list item in listview

Tags: android, listview

I start this activity (startactivityforresult) containing listview and an edittext to search through it. When the user clicks on the list item, OnItemSelected is supposed to return the selected list item to previous activity. I click on the list item and nothing happens. Why ?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_origin);

    i = getIntent();

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.loginlist, orig);

    EditText et;

    lv.setAdapter(aa);

    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before, int count) {

            aa.getFilter().filter(cs);

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


        }

    });

    lv.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            selected = orig[position];

            i.putExtra("selection", selected);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, i);
            finish();

        }
    });


}
}
```

Comment: You should use OnItemClickedListener instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your listview listener.

for example:

```
      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           //here you can apply your logic.
        }
    });
```